# Why is count() not correct?

Tags: mysql

[**SqlFidlle here.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2480c/25)

MySQL query 1:

```
SELECT 
    n.Type as Type,
    n.UserIdn as UserIdn,
    u.Username as Username,
    n.NewsIdn as NewsIdn,
    n.Header as Header,
    n.Text as Text,
    n.Tags as Tags,
    n.ImageLink as ImageLink,
    n.VideoLink as VideoLink,
    n.DateCreate as DateCreate,
    COALESCE(l.Uplikes,0) as Uplikes,
    COALESCE(ld.DownLikes,0) as DownLikes
FROM News n 
    left join (Select LikeIdn,NewsIdn,Count(*) as UpLikes FROM Likes WHERE Type='up') as l ON l.NewsIdn=n.NewsIdn
    left join (Select LikeIdn,NewsIdn,Count(*) as DownLikes FROM Likes WHERE Type='down') as ld ON ld.NewsIdn=n.NewsIdn
    left join Users u on u.UserIdn = n.UserIdn
    WHERE NewsIdn = '905554' AND (COALESCE(l.Uplikes,0) - COALESCE(ld.DownLikes,0)) < 20 AND DateCreate < STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-01 18:22:02', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
ORDER BY l.UpLikes Desc LIMIT 0, 10
```

MySQL query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM Likes WHERE NewsIdn = '905554' AND Type = 'up'
```

Problem happens because `Uplikes` is not equal to `mysql_num_rows(SELECT * FROM Likes WHERE NewsIdn = '$NewsIdn' AND Type = 'up')`.

Can anyone spot my error?

Comment: `... NewsIdn = '905554' AND Type = 'up'`there is only 1 row with both conditions

Comment: may be i can get answer if question have downvote?

Comment: @jcho360 and? why num_rows == 1 and from main query we get 4 ?  see rows table `Likes` please - she have only 1 row for `NewsIdn = '905554'`..

Comment: @learner some guys are downvoting because your question explanation was so vague. I recommend be more explicit on what you want to know.

Comment: because you are making the query without the NewsIDn and you are displaying the result, take a look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2480c/54 I place 10, it's taking the second query, counting and placing it as `Uplikes` without the last where in the big query

Comment: @jcho360 sorry but i dont understand. Can you said more information please ? when i use `left join` i use `ON l.NewsIdn=n.NewsIdn`, where error and how write it query aright? P.S.: see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2480c/72 please, but it not aright also...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bad question.  Not sure why it was downvoted.  Essentially you want to do something like the following.  I put it in the SQL Fiddle and it gives you 1 up vote and 0 downvote.  I figure you can take it from there.

```
            SELECT 
            n.Type as Type,
            n.UserIdn as UserIdn,
            -- u.Username as Username,
            n.NewsIdn as NewsIdn,
            n.Header as Header,
            n.Text as Text,
            n.Tags as Tags,
            n.ImageLink as ImageLink,
            n.VideoLink as VideoLink,
            n.DateCreate as DateCreate,
            Count(Likes1.Type) as Uplikes,
            Count(Likes2.Type) as Downlikes
        FROM News n
            LEFT JOIN Likes ON Likes.NewsIdn = n.NewsIdn 
            LEFT JOIN Likes Likes1 ON Likes.id = Likes1.id AND Likes1.Type = 'up'
            LEFT JOIN Likes Likes2 ON Likes.id = Likes2.id AND Likes2.Type = 'down'
        WHERE n.NewsIdn = '905554'
```

Answer (score 0):

in this query:

```
SELECT 
   ...
    COALESCE(l.Uplikes,0) as Uplikes, -- <-- This line
    COALESCE(ld.DownLikes,0) as DownLikes
FROM News n 
    left join (Select LikeIdn,NewsIdn,Count(*) as UpLikes FROM Likes WHERE Type='up') as l ON l.NewsIdn=n.NewsIdn -- <-- This lin
  ...
    WHERE NewsIdn = '905554' AND ...-- <-- This line
```

Is grabing the value of Uplikes and displaying without checking the condition `Newsidn='905554'`

I.E: if you execute this line only you will only received 4 rows and this value is being display as Uplikes in the Big query without checking with `NewsIdn`, that's why you have a 4 in `uplikes`.

`Select LikeIdn,NewsIdn,Count(*) as UpLikes FROM Likes WHERE Type='up'`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2480c/73

**EDITED:**
Adding this: `and NewsIdn ='905554'` to the subqueries should works

```
SELECT 
            ...
        FROM News n 
            left join (Select LikeIdn,NewsIdn,Count(*) as UpLikes FROM Likes WHERE Type='up' and NewsIdn ='905554') as l ON l.NewsIdn=n.NewsIdn -- <-- This line was modified
            left join (Select LikeIdn,NewsIdn,Count(*) as DownLikes FROM Likes WHERE Type='down' and NewsIdn ='905554') as ld ON ld.NewsIdn=n.NewsIdn  <-- This line was modified
            ...
        ORDER BY l.UpLikes Desc LIMIT 0, 10;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2480c/83

Comment: but have aright wirte line `left join (Select LikeIdn,NewsIdn,Count(*) as UpLikes FROM Likes WHERE Type='up') as l ON l.NewsIdn=n.NewsIdn` that get count with check `NewsIdn` for each row form `News`?

in my query me need get count rows `FROM Likes WHERE Type='up'` AND count rows `FROM Likes WHERE Type='down'` for each row table `News`. How arign get it ?

Comment: adding `and NewsIdn ='905554'` in the subquery should be enough, I edited my answer

Comment: but how add check `NewsIdn` for cycle, that get all rows form table `News` with right values `UpLikes` and `DownLikes` ?

Comment: what do you mean with `cycle`?

Comment: it mean get **all** rows from table `News`(not only one row where `NewsIdn='905554'`).
In result i would get all rows from table `NewsIdn` (see image please - http://clip2net.com/clip/m264191/1389339262-clip-64kb.jpg), but values `UPLIKES` and values `DOWNLIKES` should been right.

P.S.: result should be next http://clip2net.com/clip/m264191/1389339754-clip-63kb.jpg

Comment: @learner that's right, you can try adding another value and you'll see the result

Comment: you dont understand. i cannt use `NewsIdn ='905554'` i can use `NewsIdn = n.NewsIdn`(example not work), that get value in cycle for each row `News`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN .